# TypeScript: Watch & compile multiple directories at the same time (monorepo)

Tags: typescript, npm, monorepo

I've been scouring the web for a solution, but haven't found anything worthwhile. Basically, I'm looking for a tool or some way to initiate TypeScript file Watching/Compiling in multiple directories at the same time.

I have a monorepo with scoped NPM packages (@test/one, @test/two, @test/three etc.) and I want to watch/compile all of them at the same time.

Doesn't look like TS supports this and there aren't really any tools that would do this either. The closest thing I found was nodemon, I could make it watch multiple directories at once, but it only supports executing a script/binary in a single location, while I would need it to execute 'tsc' in every watched directory on change.

The best thing I could do with nodemon was the following, but of course that's not a very good way to do it as it compiles all packages even if only one changes:

```
npx nodemon --watch test-shared-api --watch test-shared-redux --watch test-shared-types -e js,ts,jsx,tsx --exec "npx tsc --build test-shared-api/tsconfig.json && npx tsc --build test-shared-types/tsconfig.json && npx tsc -build test-shared-redux/tsconfig.json"
```

With concurrently I can do the following in package.json, which is better, but still could be done better:

```
  "scripts": {
"ts-watch-shared-types": "tsc -p packages/@test-shared/test-shared-types/tsconfig.json -w",
"ts-watch-shared-api": "tsc -p packages/@test-shared/test-shared-api/tsconfig.json -w",
"ts-watch-shared-redux": "tsc -p packages/@test-shared/test-shared-redux/tsconfig.json -w",
"ts-shared-watch": "concurrently -k -n w: npm:ts-watch-shared-*"
  },
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You can try using [TypeScript project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) with [`tsc -b --watch`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#tsc--b-commandline), though the functionality is very new and has some bugs (as of September 2018).

Comment: that's a very good option to compile references!
another option if have you some non-referencing packages, is having a tool like lerna to start watch commands from the root and then set it in the IDE to start it.

in this case you would be independent like with concurrently, but still could define watch commands at the individual level of the packages

Answer (score 1):

You can launch a **build pipeline**, this is a common approach in monorepo architecture.
I am in the same case as you and I managed to get it working like this (example with turborepo):

- make a global package.json script `"start:dev-watch": "turbo run start:dev-watch"`
- In the main package.josn create the script: `"start:dev-watch": "nodemon src/index.ts"` (I use nodemon with ts-node installed so I can run directly ts files, which works great for debugging)
- in each of the project package.json that you want to build, create the script: `"build:watch": "tsc -w"`

That way, **when you launch the `npm run start:dev-watch` command in the parent directory, it will start all of your `start:dev-watch` scripts**.